# Android: how to get notified when a widget is tapped

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to get a notification when the user taps/clicks on a widget?

Is there something similar to onClick()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `AppWidgetProvider` and register listeners there. Since in Widgets all view are created via `RemoteViews` you must use methods on them - e.g. [`setOnClickPendingIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Here is a small example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider

Comment: thanks i have read through the example, but i dont quite understand why i need to start an activity with the pending intent. actually i only want to perform some background operation when the widget is clicked.

Comment: Because Widgets are not part of your app's process. They are executed in another process. So they need a cross-process way to notify you of an event. Hence an Intent.

Comment: ok thanks, but then how do i receive the clicks in this target activity? i tried interception onKeyDown but it isnt called.

Comment: You don't get any events in target activity. You target activity is invoked via PendingIntent. You can add custom data to pending intent if you need it.

Comment: hm, if i dont get any events, that doesnt solve my problem then? i just want to react to clicks on the widget.

Comment: More detail: in the example given, when user clicks a widget, an intent will be sent to your activity. You can add som data to this intent via `intent.putExtra("someName", data)` and the in activity you can retrieve it via `activity.getIntent().getExtra("someName")`.

Comment: thank you but also this extra data doesnt help me, if there is no point where i can be notified when the user taps/clicks on the widget.

Comment: Even more: Widgets are not directly built via code as normal Activities and Views are. Their views are built via RemoteViews. So Widgets can do what RemoteViews can do. Dig into RemoteViews to understand more what can be done with them.

Comment: Have you looked at example? There is a `views.setOnClickPendingIntent(..)` method that registers for clicks. But it is different than normal click handlers - it can not execute your code. It just invokes a preset Intent - in the example the intent starts the `ExampleActivity` activity.

Comment: You can set an `PendingIntent` to start an Activity, invoke a Service or send a Broadcast. That's it. You must live with that. You can even add some custom data (if you have several click listeners and want to distinguish between them): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: sorry even after reading through all the documentation i am still stuck here. my ExampleActivity is not even instantiated...